# Using meta.json file in syntribos for referencing more than one variable in the template file

Tags: openstack

I am using Syntribos for Penetration Testing my REST Services. Every Request has a Header Parameter called cookie like pasted below which contains 3 dynamic parameters which needs to be replaced.

I have written a Python Extension to get these values from the preceding login request and pass it to the subsequent request.

To do this I am using meta.json file and using this in my template file.

But at runtime only the first variable is replaced everytime.

Please let me know if this is the expected functionality of Syntribos (meta.json variables)?

***Actual Cookie Parameter:***

```
Cookie: activeUser=xxxx;auth_key=fe9kj7i67dbgitg3h7f9kv8d8d;csrf=ipfpt2gqi56mvmq93d4gn2afc3
```

***Syntribos Template (using meta.json variables):***

```
Cookie: activeUser=|ACTIVE_USER|;dm_auth_key=|AUTH_KEY|;dm_csrf=|CSRF|
```

In the above template, always `activeUser` header parameter is replaced.

*Note: All the above variables correctly return the values during runtime when used individually.*